# What is the *simplest* way to grep out a regex group per line in a shell-oneliner?

Tags: regex, perl, sed, grep

I want to perform

```
s/please (\S+) this/\1/
```

on a file, in one line, in my shell.

I am looking for the **shortest** and **easiest to remember** solution with **each** of grep, sed and perl.

---

Example file `example.txt`:

```
please grep this
please sed this
I am grumpy cat
please perl this
```

Example output of `[the program] [your options] [your way of writing the regex] example.txt`:

```
grep
sed
perl
```

---

Things I have tried that I expected to work, but did not:

```
grep "please (\S*)" example.txt
grep "please (\\S*)" example.txt
grep -o "please (\S*)" example.txt
grep -o "^please (\\S*)" example.tx
sed -E "s/^please (.*)/\1/" example.txt
sed -E "s/^please (.*)/\1/g" example.txt
sed -E "s/^please (.*)/\1/p" example.txt
sed -rn "s/^please (\w+) /\1/" example.txt
sed -rn "s/^please (\w+) /\1/g" example.txt
sed -rn "s/^please (\S+) /\1/p" example.txt
sed -rn "s/^please (\S+) /\0/" example.txt
sed -rn "s/^please ([a-zA-Z]+) /\\1/p" example.txt
perl -p -e 's/please (\w+) /$1/' example.txt
perl -p -e 's/.*please (\w+) /$1/' example.txt
perl -p -e 's/.*please (\w+) /\1/' example.txt
perl -p -e 's/.*please (\S*).*/\1/' example.txt
perl -p -e 's/.*please (\S*).*/$1/' example.txt
perl -p -e 's/please (\S+)/$1/g' example.txt
perl -p -n -e 's/.*please (\w+) .*/$1/g' example.txt
perl -p -n -e 'print if s/.*please (\w+) .*/$1/g' example.txt
perl -p -n -e 'print if s/.*please (\w+) .*/\1/g' example.txt
perl -n -e 'print if s/please (\w+) /\1/g' example.txt
perl -n -e 's/please (\w+) /\1/g' example.txt
perl -n -e 's/.*please (\w+)/\1/g' example.txt
cat example.txt | perl -ne 's/.*please (\w+) .*/\1/'
perl -n -e 's/please (\w+) /$1/ and print' example.txt
perl -n -e 's/please (\S+) /$1/ and print' example.txt
```

---

Extra notes:

- I am not interested in solutions that use columns, e.g. using `cut`, or other solutions for the example problem that are less powerful than regular expressions. The point is to capture groups.
- Extended regex (e.g. `+`) must be supported.
- Each non-regex option given, say `-p` in a perl invocation, should be briefly explained for the sake of people who just want to google a quick answer.

Comment: If you consider downvoting this question because it is asking for something that is supposed to be simple, please try to find an actually working answer first - after half an hour reading through grep cross-platform problems and sed escaping rules you might agree that it is not.

Comment: Questions are very rarely downvoted because they are asking something simple, but often - as in this case - they are downvoted and closed *because the poster has made no effort of his own to solve the problem*. Questions that just describe a requirement and request a solution never go down well; on the other hand, if the poster can show that he has tried his best to find a solution and shows those efforts he will almost always get help to complete the work he has started.

Comment: I have added the first 27 out of the 140 ways I have tried.

Answer (score 3):

```
 sed  -n '/^.*please \(.*\) this.*$/{s//\1/;p}' example.txt
 perl -ne 'print if s/^.*please (.*) this.*$/$1/' example.txt
```

Comment: Questions: The sed one: Why is it necessary to use `/^.*` instead of `/please`? Similarly, are you required to match up to the `.*$` - I thought this to be done automatically if not specified. Is there a reason you add modifier `;` and the `{}`?

Comment: Perl one: Is there a simpler alternative to using `-n` in combination with `print if`? Will the `(.*)` in the middle not become greedy? Is it precisely equivalent to your sed solution or will it behave differently for certain inputs? Is there a grep implementation that behaves the same way?

Comment: @nh2 The re fragment `^.*` looks superfluous (I'm sure it is in this case). However, it does have one important effect: it cause the re to match the _last_ `please .* this` in the string, rather than the first.

Answer (score 0):

If your grep has pcre compiled in:

```
$ grep -Po 'please \K.*(?= this)'
```

Unfortunately, `(?= ...)` (zero-width lookahead) only supports constant-width expressions.

The perl version is trivially different

```
$ perl -nE 'say $& if /please \K.*(?= this)/'
```

or

```
$ perl -nE '/please \K.*(?= this)/ and say $&'
```

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but I don't think this lets me refer to the groups I matched in the output.

Comment: @nh2 You are wrong. You get your required output from feeding in `example.txt`. In the grep case, it's the really useful `-o` option. The perl equivalent is `$&`. I use zero-width look behind (`(?<=...)` which is best optimised with `\K`), and zero-width lookahead (`(?=...)`). The combination of `-o` and `\K` is a handy way to solve many problems in grep.